# Split running total into positive and negative DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to DAX and to Stackoverflow. Looking for your expertise.

I need to split running total into positive and negative amounts.

What I have so far.

1. Data model: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JARY6.png)
2. Data: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkSU6.png)
3. Running total calculation:

```
    Running total:=
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Stock[Stock movement]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(DimDate),
            DimDate[Date]<=MAX(DimDate[Date])
        )
    )
```

[running total result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeS1c.png)

4. I need to create a measure in Power BI to SUM all positive and negative running totals separately by category for each period.
   Desired result:[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szage.png)

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you showing data in a matrix?

Comment: Matrix or table. It should work in both. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not tested this, but it should work:

```
PositivMovment =
CALCULATE (
    [Running total],
    FILTER ( 'Stock', VAR __temp = [Running total] RETURN __temp > 0 )
)

NegativMovment =
CALCULATE (
    [Running total],
    FILTER ( 'Stock', VAR __temp = [Running total] RETURN __temp < 0 )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, msta42a, for pushing me in the right direction. I edited your measures a little and now they are perfect.